# Qml style Button

Tags: qt, button, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have structure for my page and I want add some `ButtonStyle` for my button (I followed example from documentation), now I have a question, why I can't add `style` for this button. Below is my page structure

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
Page
{
...
header: ToolBar {
    ...
    RowLayout{
        Button {
        ...
        style: ButtonStyle {
            background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 25
            border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
            border.color: "#888"
            radius: 4
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
                GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen QtQuick Controls 2 `Button` (`import QtQuick.Controls 2.0`), for which styling can be done directly with `background` (i.e `QtQuick.Controls.Styles` is not needed)  ... [Customizing Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html). On the other hand if you want to use a `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` Button then you need to change your import to  `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4` along with `QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4` and your styling will work ... [Qt Quick Controls Styles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrolsstyles-index.html).

With QtQuick Controls 2, you can style `Button` directly with `background` like this:

```
Button {
    id:control
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 25
        border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
        border.color: "#888"
        radius: 4
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
            GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
        }
    }
}
```